# My Character from Mixamo has no shading in Blender

Tags: shaders

When I import my character as a Collada file - it looks completely flat with no shading. I have not seen that before in Blender. Why is this happening?

[image: Imported character]

Comment: Maybe custom normals. Check "geometry data" in "object data" property panel.

Comment: I found that the Material Properties>Viewport Display>Colour is half white and half alpha. On a second file that does not have this issue, it is completely white. See https://imgur.com/gallery/6hOctJa How do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Material Properties>Viewport Display>Colour - then click the colour and slide the Alpha to 1